# How to get external monitor brightness in Windows PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi, brightness

I have used:

```
Get-Ciminstance -Namespace root/WMI -ClassName WmiMonitorBrightness
```

this for getting my screen current brightness but it only shows my laptops screen brightness. Is there a way to get the brightness of external monitor?

Comment: Maybe you can filter by `InstanceName` : `Get-CimInstance - Namespace root/WMI  -Query "SELECT * from WmiMonitorBrightness WHERE InstanceName ='[you exetrnal monitor instacne name]' `

Comment: but how I can get my external monitor instance name because I can only see my laptop monitor instance name after my command.